# Firefox will not update CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser-cache

I have an element with the class `.ui-menu .ui-menu` that has the style of `margin-left:25px;`. I have removed this, so that it is `margin-left: 0px;`. However, when I refresh the page, it's still displaying this style, and the 'inspect element' window tells me that according to the css file it's reading `.ui-menu .ui-menu` still has a rule set for `margin-left: 25px;`.

I have tried using <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Shift + F5</kbd>, <kbd>Shift + Ctrl + F5</kbd>… I've manually cleared all cache, shut the computer down and restarted it. I'm about to uninstall Firefox completely and reinstall it to see if THAT even works. I've also tried renaming the CSS file, and re-linking to it with its new name… and then Firefox stops reading the CSS file entirely, because it's not updating the headers or footers to see that it's been changed so everything goes unstyled!

I don't have this issue in GC, Opera, Safari, not even in IE. Am I doing something wrong?

As to your questions:

- I'm using Firefox instead of other browsers because I can't control what browser people who visit my site are using. As far as website design goes, this is a pretty basic understanding.
- I've run the site through validation here: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fthesciencefacility.icyboards.net%2Findex.php&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

  Most of the issues here are just cross-browser stuff, plus some embarrassing color issues. if you can find something here I can't, please mention it!
- The site is not self-hosted. It's a forum service through IcyBoards, if you're at all familiar with it.

Comment: Have you tried validating your CSS?

Comment: Are you sure Firefox isn't calling a remote server ? I don't know, maybe you have a local version and a remote one, and you didn't pay attention to the URL !

Comment: Fixing all the *errors* not related to IE proprietary filters would be a good start.

Comment: @cimmanon I added my validation link in the OP. If you can find something there I can't, please tell me! I'm far from an expert at this, lmao.

Comment: @RomainBraun I use a host called IcyBoards which, to my knowledge, does not do this.

Comment: That is W3 validation. Not W3Schools validation. Unaffiliated. http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @minitech oh hey, my fault, sorry about that, lol. Thank you for catching that though.